# PHP:: Selectively pack zip-archives from files in folder

Tags: php, arrays, split, zip, filenames

I have a folder containing a few hundred files. 
The filename is always similiar to ######_### - #######.ext What they all have in common is the delimiter " - ". Files with the same name prior to the delimiter should be regarded as the same article group.

What I want to achieve is to run a php-file that scans the entire folder and creates zip-archives from those files. Each archive should contain all files from one article group and be named like the filename prior to the delimiter to know about its content.

Example (filenames; yes, they may have whitespace):

- Article_1 - Subtype a.ext
- Article_1 - Subtype b.ext
- Article_2 - Subtype a.ext
- Article_2 - Subtype b.ext
- Article_2 - Subtype c.ext

After running the process there should be 2 archives (in this case). One named Article_1.zip containing the first two files as they form a group. The second file containing the remaining three files and named Article_2.zip as they form a group.

I fiddled around half the day with array_count_values, array_key_exists and more, but I'm stuck at that point. Besides I'm sure that my approach to get the part prior to the delimiter as filename is already way complicated and overdone.

I'd greatly appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Don't know how to do the zip archives, but with this: `$files = glob("your/path/*.*");
 $data = [];
 
 foreach($files as $file) {
  $explode = explode("-", $file);
  $data[$explode[0]][] = $file; 
 }` You would have all files grouped up in a sub array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php code to separate files based on article name is as follows:-

```
<?php
$array = Array('Article_1 - Subtype a.ext','Article_1 - Subtype b.ext','Article_2 - Subtype a.ext','Article_2 - Subtype b.ext','Article_2 - Subtype c.ext');
$new_array = array(); 
foreach($array as $arr) { 
    $exploded_array = explode("-", $arr); 
    $new_array[$exploded_array[0]][] = $arr; 
}
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/389841

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick, had to fiddle around some time with the zip-functionality, but now it works!:D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot again. Posting the final code that does the trick:
(MV is a subfolder where to files to be packed are stored)

```
$files = scandir('MV/');
$arr2 = array();

foreach($files as $arr) 
{ 
    $exploded_array = explode(" - ", $arr); 
    $arr2[$exploded_array[0]][] = $arr;
}

for($k=0;$k<count($arr2);$k++)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $key = key($arr2); 
    $title = './'.$key.'.zip';

    if ($zip->open($title, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) 
    {
            exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }
        for($l=0;$l<count($arr2[$key]);$l++)
        {
            $zip->addFile('MV/'.$arr2[$key][$l],$arr2[$key][$l]);
        }

    next($arr2);
    echo 'The zip archive ', $title,' contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files.';
    echo '<br>';
    $zip->close();
}

?>
```